# C library to generate / extract metadata for file types (audio OR image Or etc)

Tags: c, metadata

the objective is to extract metadata from file types. I know about these:
TagLib for audio files
Exiv2 for images (but this is for C++)

1. I'm not sure about TagLib working properly for C programs. I could not find something of that order too.
2. Exiv2 is a C++ library.

Do you know any libraries I can use with C programs?
Or if there are other libraries, how do I interface them with my C program?

Comment: If you're just looking at MP3 for audio, manually parsing ID3 really isn't that hard, and makes good practice. Anyway, I saw it done in Common Lisp, so it has to be posible in C (anyway, C is very good at binary parsing).

Comment: Yes, I know manual parsing - its the last 128 bytes. But I need external libraries because I want to use standard libraries already implemented. One library for all audio files, library for image files and so on.

Comment: Ok. I see. I try to find one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- The **libexif C EXIF** library is a library
  written in pure portable C. It reads and writes EXIF metainformation
  from and to image files.
- **GNU Libextractor** is a library used to
  extract meta data from files. GNU libextractor uses helper-libraries
  (plugins) to perform the actual extraction. As a result, GNU
  libextractor can be extended simply by installing additional plugins.
  Currently, libextractor supports the following formats: HTML, MAN,
  PS, DVI, OLE2 (DOC, XLS, PPT), OpenOffice (sxw), StarOffice (sdw),
  FLAC, MP3 (ID3v1 and ID3v2), OGG, WAV, S3M (Scream Tracker 3), XM
  (eXtended Module), IT (Impulse Tracker), NSF(E) (NES music), SID (C64
  music), EXIV2, JPEG, GIF, PNG, TIFF, DEB, RPM, TAR(.GZ), LZH, LHA,
  RAR, ZIP, CAB, 7-ZIP, AR, MTREE, PAX, CPIO, ISO9660, SHAR, RAW, XAR
  FLV, REAL, RIFF (AVI), MPEG, QT and ASF. Also, various additional
  MIME types are detected.
- **The Metadata Extraction Tool** was
  developed by the National Library of New Zealand to programmatically
  extract preservation metadata from a range of file formats like PDF
  documents, image files, sound files Microsoft office documents, and
  many others.
- **TagLib** is a library for reading and editing the
  meta-data of several popular audio formats. Currently it supports
  both ID3v1 and ID3v2 for MP3 files, Ogg Vorbis comments and ID3 tags
  and Vorbis comments in FLAC, MPC, Speex, WavPack TrueAudio, WAV,
  AIFF, MP4 and ASF files.

Comment: GNU Libextractor is unfortunately GPL and not LGPL.

Answer (score 0):

This is a very vague question. For images some common C libraries include: [LibExif](http://libexif.sourceforge.net/) for reading Exif metadata, [Libtiff](http://www.remotesensing.org/libtiff/) for reading TIFF files (and their metadata), [libgeotiff](http://trac.osgeo.org/geotiff/) to read geodata from GeoTIFF files, and so on. It highly depends on what file types you are trying to read metadata from (and what types of metadata you are trying to read).

Answer (score 0):

If possible Adobes XMP library should be used for portability among the terrible fragmentation of the metadata world.

Adobe published an source code SDK to not only read but also modify the metadata.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extensible_Metadata_Platform